# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction

Tags: java, neo4j

Trying java Program to connect to Neo4J i got following error

```
/home/mkgs/Desktop/placement/
Mar 21, 2014 2:53:41 PM org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog doInternalRecovery
INFO: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/home/mkgs/Desktop/placement/nioneo_logical.log.1Recovery started ...
Mar 21, 2014 2:53:42 PM org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog doInternalRecovery
INFO: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/home/mkgs/Desktop/placement/index/lucene.log.1]. Recovery started ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction cannot be cast to javax.transaction.Transaction
    at neo.main(neo.java:22)
```

The java code is as follows

```
//import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import javax.transaction.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;

public class neo {
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    final String DB_PATH = "/home/mkgs/Desktop/placement/";
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    System.out.println(DB_PATH);

    graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

    Transaction tx = (Transaction) graphDb.beginTx();

    try  {
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, null);
        ExecutionResult result = (ExecutionResult) engine.execute("START 
n=node(*) MATCH n-[r]-m RETURN type(r), count(*) ORDER BY count(*) desc");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    finally {
        ((org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction) tx).finish();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use

```
import javax.transaction.Transaction;
```

but use

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
```

This is what's causing your `ClassCastException`.